# Foreach PHP : how to put a value on the table into a variable

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to create a variable that contains the data from one of the tables created by using foreach in PHP, using CodeIgniter. tersebuat variables would I use to see the detail of the data from the database which I will show in the form of pop up.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="ab">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th> # </th>
                    <th> Invoice </th>
                    <th> Product </th>
                    <th> date </th>
                    <th> suplier </th>
                    <th> Description </th>
                    <th> Detail </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php $numb=0;foreach($proses as $isi){$numb++; ?>

                <tr>
                    <td> <?php echo $numb;?> </td>
                    <td> <?php echo $isi->invoice;?> </td>
                    <td> <?php echo $isi->name;?> </td>
                    <td> <?php echo $isi->date;?> </td>
                    <td> <?php echo $suplier;?> </td>
                    <td> --- </td>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <a class="btn blue btn-outline sbold" data-toggle="modal" href="#full"> Detail </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>


                    <?php } ?>

            </tbody>
        </table>
```

sample output from the program :

```
1|000012|Noodle|03-Mar-2016|Suplier01|--|(Detail)|
2|000044|Rice  |05-Mar-2016|Suplier03|--|(Detail)|
```

How to enter an invoice number `000012` into a variable (eg, `$invoice`) on click by `invoice details`?

Comment: `how to enter an invoice number 000012 into a variable. (eg, $ invoice) and every time I click the invoice number details will be entered into a variable.` this is totally unclear.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to translate the title into English. Now I have changed the title

Comment: This question is really hard to read. Did this go through machine translation or something..?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to have the details appearing in the modal.

To do so, you can either:

1. print out the modal using PHP and have one modal per table row.
2. Or, have the variables as data attributes somewhere like the button itself.

For 2, example:

```
<a data-invoice="<?php echo $isi->invoice;?>" class="btn blue btn-outline sbold" data-toggle="modal" href="#full"> Detail </a>
```

Then use jquery to detect the button click and set the modal's html value.

```
$('a.btn').click(function(){
    $('.modal <your own selector here>').html($(this).data('invoice'));
});
```